Understanding the Error: "DSolve: Arguments should be ordered consistently"
I want to solve a Stokes Flow problem which is given by
$$ 0= - p_x + \mu_o u_{xx} + \rho_o g \sin{(\alpha)} + F_x  $$
$$ 0= - p_z - \rho_o g \cos{(\alpha)} + F_z  $$
where $F_x = C_x P_0 e^{-2(k_i x + k_z z)}$ and $F_z = C_z P_0 e^{-2(k_i x + k_z z)}$. In this proble, we have $p=p(x,z)$ and $u=u(x,z,t)$. Now I want to use Mathematica to solve the second equation for $p$ with the boundary condition that $p(x,h(x))=-\gamma h''(x)$. To do this I have used the follow commands:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Fsx = Cx P0 Exp[-2 (ki x + Kz z)]
Fsz = Cz P0 Exp[-2 (ki x + Kz z)]
SFx = -D[p[x, z], x] + \[Mu]o D[u[x, z, t], {z, 2}] + \[Rho]o g Sin[\[Alpha]] + Fsx
SFz = -D[p[x, z], z] - \[Rho]o g Cos[\[Alpha]] + Fsz

which define the system in Mathematica. I can then solve for $p$ using the following command:
pressure = FullSimplify[p[x, z] /. DSolve[{SFz == 0, p[x, h[x]] == -\[Gamma] h''[x]}, 
 p[x, z], {x, z}][[1]]]

This command works fine and I can verify the boundary condition is satisfied correctly via the command
pressure /. z->h[x]

which outputs $-\gamma h''(x)$ as expected. Now I want to differentiate this function and plug it into the first equation in the system. I then have a second-order PDE for $u$ which should be solvable with the boundary conditions that $u(x,0,t)=0$ and $u_z(x,h(x),t)=0$. To do this in Mathematica I am trying the following commands:
SFx1 = SFx /. -D[p[x, z], x] -> D[pressure, x]
vel = FullSimplify[u[x, z, t] /. DSolve[{SFx1 == 0, u[x, 0, t] == 0, Derivative[0, 1, 
   0][u][x, h[x], t] == 0}, u[x, z, t], {x, z, t}][[1]]]

However this command is giving the error: "DSolve::conarg :  The arguments should be ordered consistently". I think this issue has something to do with the fact that $z=h(x)$ has dependence on $x$; however, I have the same thing in the command for pressure so I don't quite see what is different here. Does anyone have any insight into what I am doing wrong and how to better understand this error?
EDIT: Note that this system actually should be solvable by hand without too much difficulty. I believe the solution is given by
$$     u = \frac{1}{\mu_o} \Bigg(\bigg[\gamma h'''(x) - \rho_o g h'(x) \cos{\alpha} - \rho_o g \sin{\alpha} + C_z P_0 h'(x) \psi(x,h) + \frac{C_z P_0 k_i}{K_z}\psi(x,h) \bigg]\left(\frac{1}{2}z^2 -zh\right) $$
$$    +\frac{C_xP_0}{4K_z^2}\left(\psi(x,z)-\psi(x,0) \right) +\frac{C_zP_0k_i}{8K_z^3}\left(\psi(x,z)-\psi(x,0) \right) + z \psi(x,h) \left(\frac{C_xP_0}{2K_z}+\frac{C_z P_0 k_i}{4 K_z^2} \right) \Bigg)$$
however I want to use Mathematica to confirm this is correct. I can type this in and then verify that the boundary conditions are satisfied but I would feel much more confident if I could have Mathematica confirm this. Note that I have defined $\psi(x,z) = e^{-2(k_i x + k_z z)}$.
EDIT 2: For anyone experiencing a similar issue, the accepted answer works or the following command also works:
Simplify[vx[z] /. DSolve[{(SFx1 /. \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
  TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
  Derivative], MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, z, t] -> vx''[z]) == 
  0, vx[0] == 0, vx'[h[x]] == 0}, vx[z], z][[1]]]

where essentially I just use a replacement rule to substitute $vx(z)$ for $u_{zz}(x,z,t)$.

it does not like the BC Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][x, h[x], t] == 0 because you are taking derivative with respect to the second argument, which is z but you have x in there.  FOr example, if you replace h[x] by say 0 then the error goes away. You need to have specific value in the second slot. Even h[4] works. But not h[x]

This isn't an issue for say the "pressure" command just because that BC is enforced on $p(x,h(x))$ and not on the derivative? It seems to me that it's essentially the same thing no? Is there a way around this? Mathematically speaking there shouldn't be any issue with enforcing a Neumann BC at $z=h(x)$. I actually can solve this by hand, however, I would like Mathematica to do it for me so I can ensure I didn't make any silly mistakes (such as dropping a sign or incorrectly differentiating/integrating these exponential terms)

The pressure one using Dirichlet BC. Not Neumann like with the second one. This could be the reason. Someone else might know for sure. I am just pointing out the reason for the error.

Thank you for your insight! I will ty to search for other similar questions and how they circumvent this.

Actually it gives an error even on Dirichlet BC. Here is a very simple example pde = D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0; bc = {u[0, t] == 1, u[x, h[x]] == 0, (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}; DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}] which gives DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.  I do not know why you did not get this on your pressure ode. No time now to look into it. Just wanted to point this.  Replacing the bc to bc = {u[0, t] == 1, u[x, 0] == 1, (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}; the error goes away as expected.

By the construction of the algorithm DSolve for a PDE, all unknown functions have to be functions of the complete set of variables. If a function does not depend on on a specified variable, say $t \in \{t,x,y\}$, add the equation $\partial_t u[t,x,y]==0$. The solutions are delivered as a complete set of rules for all functions defined algebraically or as a discrete interpolating function  over the total region of integration specified in $\mathbb R^3$, too. This uniform concept avoids an infinite tree of possible notation variation parsing on input.

Thank you this works! Interestingly, it also works if I use a replacement rule to substitute $v''(z)$ for $u_{zz}(x,z,t)$.
